# MS outlook Work Using JAVA

Tags: sql, eclipse, ms-office, java

I have an Idea of integrating our own company Tool with MS outlook,

Our company tool is Incident or Service Request tool .We communicate with User using the Service Number generated in THe tool(This servce Number is generated when A Client Logs the Problem in our tool) with MS outlook,

However I just know JAVA and not C#(So I am Comfortable in JAVA programming).

Is there any way That I can write code which can search the Outlook Files in my inbox, Based on some search Criteria, and display it back .

Any help is appreciated :)

Thaks rajesh

Comment: Exchange offers a web-service interface, this way you can communicate directly with the server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(v=exchg.140).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285691/119179

Shows how to read an inbox with the java mail API which is independent of Outlook.